# Can't move from the login to the register activity when running the app

Tags: java, android

I have an issue in this piece of code here and i always get an error and the app crashes when i try to click the text view associated to that listener. Instead of moving from the login to the register activity it just crashes. Some help?

```
registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
  @Override 
  public void onClick(View view) { 
    Intent registerIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class); 
    Login.this.startActivity(registerIntent); 
  } 
});
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/62GBA.jpg

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot, copy and paste the code in here instead

Comment: `registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                Login.this.startActivity(registerIntent);

            }
        });`

Comment: i think ur not registered Register activity into manifest

Comment: Please post the code of your whole Activity class.

Comment: The problem was with the manifest, i solved it now and it works, thanks lots :D

Answer (score 1):

if you can provide error logs it will help

ensure that Register Activity is declared in your manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Register"
    />
```

Comment: Well that's something, i thought it would be written there by default after i created it. Thanks lots, now it works fine :D

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18879309)

Comment: @ChristianHujer except it answered his question... So it is an answer...